# Initializing Hashtables in Java?

Tags: java

In C# you can initialize Hashtables (and many other types of objects) using code like this -

```
Hashtable table = new Hashtable {{1, 1}, {2, 2}};
```

Is there anything like this in Java or do you have to just declare the Hashtable first and then manually put items in it one by one?

Comment: In both C# and Java there are better alternatives to a `Hashtable` class: in C#, prefer `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, and in Java prefer `HashMap<K, V>`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is answered elsewhere but you can use an anonymous subclass:

```
new HashMap<Integer, Integer>() {{ put(1, 1); put(2, 2); }};
```

Lot's of boiler plate, but still a one-liner :).  This will, unfortunately, also complain about the missing serialVersionUID constant which you can either add or ignore the warning on.

This is called an instance initializer block, more information [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).

Comment: There's a potential memory leak here, though. Because you're creating an anonymous class, it'll have a reference to its enclosing class (ie the class in which this code appears). That means that as long as this `Map` is still around, so is that enclosing class. If the enclosing class has a shorter lifecycle than the `Map` (for instance, the `Map` is long-living and the enclosing class was some builder responsible for creating the `Map`), then you've got a memory leak.

Comment: yeah, one of those "clever, but not recommended" ideas.  DBI considered harmful ;-)

Comment: I love how the accepted answer has some potentially disastrous side effects.

Answer (score 9):

In [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), if you want an immutable map you can use:

```
Map<K,V> m = ImmutableMap.of(k1, v1, k2, v2, k3, v3, k4, v4, k5, v5);
```

up to 5 Key/Value pairs.

Beyond that, you can use their [ImmutableMap.Builder](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/index.html) class:

```
ImmutableMap<String, Integer> WORD_TO_INT = ImmutableMap.builder()
       .put("one", 1)
       .put("two", 2)
       .put("three", 3)
       .build();
```

Still not nearly as nice as in C#, but the fluent API is a bit helpful.

Comment: +1, alternately write your own utility: `makeMap(A a, B b, Object... remaining)` and then manually iterate over the remaining Objects casting them to A and B alternately and adding them to the returned map.  Not type-safe but concise (useful for test-code maybe).

Comment: not only would that not be type-safe, but you can't even enforce the proper even-number arg count.  But yes, it could e useful in less formal settings such as test-code.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to initialize a **HashMap** (HashTable is obsolete) you can use an static initialization block.

Example:

```
private static Map<String, String> map;

static {
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("name1", "value1");
    map.put("name2", "value2");
    ....
}
```

Hope this helped, have Fun!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Hashtable<Integer, String> ht = new Hashtable<Integer, String>(){
    {
        put(1,"One");
        put(2,"Two");
        put(3,"Three");
    }
};
```

Comment: Will this also have same memory leak problem as mentioned by @yshavit in the comment.

Answer (score 3):

Another answer (besides the obvious "no -- no native language way to do this"):

Create a Tuple class with a static factory method with a fancy-pants "_" name for brevity:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

class Tuple<T1,T2> {
    private T1 t1;
    private T2 t2;
    public Tuple(T1 t1, T2 t2) {
         this.t1 = t1; this.t2 = t2;
    }
    public T1 getT1() {return t1;}
    public T2 getT2() {return t2;}

    static public <X,Y> Tuple<X,Y> _(X t1, Y t2) { return new Tuple<X,Y>(t1,t2); }
    static public <X,Y> Map<X,Y> mapFor(Tuple<X,Y>... tuples) {
        Map<X,Y> map = new HashMap<X,Y>();
        for( Tuple<X,Y> tuple: tuples ) {
           map.put(tuple.getT1(), tuple.getT2());
        }
        return map;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String,Integer> map = Tuple.mapFor( _("A", 1), _("B", 2), _("C",3));
    }
}
```

If you want to allow variations on what kind of backing map is produced, you can just pass that in instead:

```
    static public <X,Y> Map<X,Y> mapFor(Map<X,Y> map, Tuple<X,Y>... tuples) {
        for( Tuple<X,Y> tuple: tuples ) {
           map.put(tuple.getT1(), tuple.getT2());
        }
        return map;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a thing called double brace initialization, which isn't as nice...

```
Hashtable table = new Hashtable() {
    {
        table.put(1, 1);
        table.put(2, 2);
    }
};
```

You could even specify using anonymous array notation, and then iterate over it yourself, like this:

```
Hashtable table = new Hashtable() {
    {
        for (int[] entry : new int[][] { { 1, 1 }, { 2, 2 } }) {
            table.put(entry[0], entry[1]);
        }
    }
};
```

Perhaps make a utility function if you're really missing python :)

Answer (score 0):

One of C#'s features which I quite like is its ability to initialize inline like that. Unfortunately, Java doesn't have this feature.

The Java `Hashtable` does not have any constructors which allow for this either. See a list of its constructors in the Java API documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html

Comment: More generally, Java does not support member initialization list constructors.

Answer (score 0):

A safe approach is to use `ImmutableMap.of` from Guava and optionally wrapped with `newHashSet` if mutability is needed:

```
Maps.newHashMap(ImmutableMap.of(k1, v1, ...));
```

Here's a self-written map builder for inline use, e.g. `newMap(1, "one", 2, "two", 3, "three")`.

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> newMap(final K key, final V value, final Object... elements) {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(key);
    Preconditions.checkArgument(elements.length % 2 == 0, "Array length can't be " + elements.length);

    final HashMap<Object, Object> map = Maps.newHashMap();
    map.put(key, value);
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i += 2) {
        map.put(elements[i], elements[i + 1]);
    }
    return (Map<K, V>) map;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest something like this:

```
String[] names={"albert","john","michel"};
int[] id={1234,2345,3456};
Hashtable<int,String> persons = new Hashtable<int,String>();

for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
 persons.put(id[i],names[i]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible in Java. We all suffer from that.

Comment: `HashMap` accomplishes the same thing, though.  Double-check the answers already on the post which discuss this very thing.